# Have I made a calculation mistake in this ATPL question that uses the CAP 698 Chart?

Tags: performance-calculation, atpl

I have been calculating this question but I just don't seem to get the correct answer.

**For this question use Performance Manual CAP 698 SEP1 Figure 2.3.**

Using the climb performance chart, for the single-engine aeroplane, determine the   ground distance to reach a height of 2000 ft in the following conditions:

---

Given:

OAT at take-off: 25°C

Airport pressure altitude: 1000 ft

Aeroplane mass: 3600 lb

Speed: 100 KIAS

Wind component: 15 kt Headwind

---

***My Workings***

*TAS = 104kt (from using CRP-5)

GS = 104kts - 15kts = 89kts*
Climb Gradient = 10.7% (from chart)

Still Air Distance = (2000 / 10.7) X 100 = 18,691ft

**Ground Distance = 18691 X (89/104) = 15,995ft**

---

But the CAE Oxford ATPL says that **16,850ft** is the answer.

The next closest answer is **15,750ft** which is what I would choose.

Please help me out here, thank you in advance!

[image]

---

Reference:
CAE Oxford ATPL Chapter 8, Question 4.

Comment: FWIW I also calculated 18,691. I checked your speed calc using a E6-B, I checked your use of the chart I alos got 10.7% (ish) and I also go 18,691 ft. Quite often these questions in study material print the wrong answer

Comment: @Jamiec Thank you so much for your verification! Now I can sleep in peace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relevant section (3.2.3) of [CAP 698](https://publicapps.caa.co.uk/docs/33/CAP698.pdf) explains how to calculate this as follows:

> #### Distance to Reach given height.
>
> To calculate the ground distance travelled in order to attain a given height above
> reference zero:
> a) Convert the IAS 100 kt to a TAS, assume no position error.
> b) Apply the wind component to the TAS to obtain the ground speed.
> c) Determine the climb gradient from the graph.
> d) Calculate the still air distance using the formula:
> $$\text{Still Air Distance} (ft) = \frac{\text{Height Difference} (ft)}{\text{Gradient}} \times 100$$
> e) Calculate ground distance using the formula:
> $$\text{Ground Distance} = \text{Still Air Distance} \times \frac{\text{Groundspeed}}{\text{TAS}}$$

Assuming your calculation of TAS is right, and your interpretation of the graph is right (which I agree with) you can plug this into the above calculations and confirm the answer is indeed:

**Ground Distance = 15,995ft**

However, if we play devil's advocate and reverse engineer the climb gradient from the expected answer, you'll see there might be some human/interpretation error at work.

Taking the published answer of **16,850ft** and *dividing* by $\frac{\text{Groundspeed}}{\text{TAS}}$ gives us a ground distance of **19,690ft**. Take this and Divide by 100 gives 196.9. Then doing $\frac{1}{196.9} \times \text{Height Difference} (ft)$ gives a resulting climb gradient of **10.2** - this is all just mathematics, no aviation knowledge required.

Now, can you say for sure that you've not misread/misused the chart? Once again I got the same result as you by looking at it in low def on a screen. But it's possible we both miscalculated the climb gradient.

---

Side note: I see question like this come up fairly regularly on other aviation forums, and a reasonable amount of time it is student error and a reasonable amount of time it is publication error. Make of that what you will.

Comment: Hmm interesting take on the answer. I will do the same and see what I come up with. Thank you once again @Jamiec. You sound like a ground school instructor hahaha.

Comment: I'm still convinced that both our solutions are correct. There's no way the interpretation of the chart will give us 10.2%.I have been drawing the lines on the printed version and I have not got anywhere close to 10.2%. But anyway thank you for offering your knowledge, really appreciate it.

Comment: I'm not even slightly a ground school instructor. It's been nearly 20 years since I had to learn this stuff, and embarrassingly I don't use it nearly enough as I tend to fly places where I know I have enough safety margin. But when I see a question like this I like to refresh my knowledge and try it out.